# Convert difference equation to differential equation

Tags: finite-differences

Suppose I have the following third-order difference equation:

Y[t]+aY[t-1]+bY[t-2]+cY[t-3]=G d^t

I need to convert it into a differential equation and I followed this method:

y' = y(t+1)-y(t);
y'' = y'(t+1)-y'(t) = y(t+2)-2y(t+1)+y(t)
y'''=y''(t+1)-y''(t) = y(t+3)-3y(t+2)+3y(t+1)-y(t)

Rearranging the orginal expression:

y(t+3)-3y(t+2)+3y(t+1)-y(t)+(a+3)(y(t+2)-2y(t+1)+y(t))+(3-2a+b)(y(t+1)-y(t))+(1+c+b-3a)y(t) = G d^t

Which can be converted to:
y'''+(a+3)y''+(3-2a+b)y'+(1+c+b-3a)y = G d^t

Is this procedure correct? How do I treat G d^t ?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Assuming by d^t you mean $d^t$ you got an ODE already.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the result of the difference equation is different from the differential one. For instance, if we take a simpler version of the original function: Y[t]+aY[t-1]+bY[t-2]+cY[t-3]=G.  Using mathematica, the result of the differential equation is:   G/(1 - 3 a + b + c) + E^(t Root[1 - 3 a + b + c + (3 - 2 a + b) #1 + (3 + a) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]) C[1] + E^(t Root[ 1 - 3 a + b + c + (3 - 2 a + b) #1 + (3 + a) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]) C[2] + E^(t Root[  1 - 3 a + b + c + (3 - 2 a + b) #1 + (3 + a) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]) C[3]]}}

Comment: While the result of the difference equation is: G/(1 + a + b + c) + C[1] Root[c + b #1 + a #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]^t +  C[2] Root[c + b #1 + a #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]^t +  C[3] Root[c + b #1 + a #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]^t. And this solution is correct, while the solution produced by solving the differential equation isn't

Comment: Is that surprising ? With a huge time step of $\Delta t=1$ is it true that $y'(t)=y(t+1)-y(t)$  ?